# Setting up SVN service on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, svn

Im trying to setup SVN on a VPS, Windows 2003.

Everything works fine when I run the follow on the server

```
svnserve --daemon -r c:\current\svn\twipler
```

and from Windows client (with tourtoise) svn://twipler.com works fine.

However, if I close the command line/log off from remote desktop the service stops and the client stops working.

So I've tried setting this up as a service using the following command;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin>sc create SVN binpath="\"c:\Program Files
(x86)\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r c:\current\svn\twipler" display
name="SVN Service" depends=tcpip
```

Which returns the SC help text;

```
DESCRIPTION:
     Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
USAGE:
    sc <server> create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS:
    ....
```

But it does not setup the service! I've tried a few combinations etc but with no joy!

**update**
Im also doing

```
svnservice -install --daemon --root c:\current\svn\twipler
```

which after 10 seconds or so, pops up an alert saying

Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and the started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.

I can't find installutil and am lost! Also "whoami" is CT17220\administrator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SC command-line syntax is wrong:

```
sc create SVN binpath= "\"c:\Program Files(x86)\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r c:\current\svn\twipler" displayname= "SVN Service" depend= tcpip
```

SC is dumb and needs spaces after the "=" signs. Don't ask me why. Also, you had "depends" instead of "depend".

Comment: Yes! This works. Im just sorry I don't have the rep' to upvote [have 3K+ on SO]. Many many thanks! (also you missed a space before (x86) but I figured that)... thanks again!

Comment: Ahh, crap. Good catch.

Comment: +1 finally have some rep!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
svnservice -install --daemon --root "C:\Documents and Settings\Subversion Repository"
```

At some point.

I followed these directions and didn't have much trouble.

http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/01/16/Setting_up_a_Subversion_Server_under_Windows.aspx